# It is a good practice type object pass as argument for a function with your parameter already typed?

Tags: typescript

I am working on a TypeScript project and I need to create a service function. So I create with this format:

```
interface UserService {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  complement: string;
}

const userService = ({ name, age, complement }: UserService) => {
  // CODE
};
```

Thinking about the best practices in TypeScript, is it OK to use the second format, or do I need to type the object that I will pass to as the first format?

First format:

```
 const user: UserService = {
  name: '',
  age: 0,
  complement: ''
}
```

Second format:

```
const user = {
      name: '',
      age: 0,
      complement: ''
    }
```

And in my controller, I call the function like this:

```
userService(user);
```

Comment: It's literally the same.

Comment: No it's not @RobertoZvjerković, you won't get _excess property checks_ in the second version.

Comment: Why do you want to **not** specify the type? It means your IDE can't help you by autocompleting and checking the types of properties as you type them in, prevents excess property checking, moves the error away from where the object is actually created (and makes it _much_ less specific), ... See https://tsplay.dev/m0yRaW.

Comment: @jonrsharpe
because the service function would already have the type and typing an object that already has all the information expected of the type would be too much

Comment: But it _doesn't_ have all of the information, not until the function gets called with the value, which could be some distance away (or even in another file entirely).  And if you're going to say "no it's always just used on the next line", then _inline_ it into the call and get all of the benefits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A selection of reasons why you should always use the first format:

- Documentation; the next person who reads the code (including you, in the future) can see exactly what you expected that object to be.
- Your IDE can help you autocomplete the property names, because it can also see exactly what you expected that object to be, so it knows what properties it should have.
- You get *excess property checking*, so you don't include properties that aren't actually needed in a `UserService`.

  That can be beneficial for avoiding accidents, but also helps out if you later *change* `UserService`, renaming or removing some properties, then the compiler can lead you right to the objects where the change is needed (rather than the function calls they're used in).
- You get clearer error messages, *closer to the error*, when the compiler knows what type an object is supposed to be when it's *defined* rather than when it's *used*.

  Compare how much harder it is to figure out the problem from:

  ```
  Argument of type '{ name: string; age: number; compliment: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UserService'.
    Property 'complement' is missing in type '{ name: string; age: number; compliment: string; }' but required in type 'UserService'.(2345)
  ```

  than from:

  ```
  Type '{ name: string; age: number; compliment: string; }' is not assignable to type 'UserService'.
    Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'compliment' does not exist in type 'UserService'. Did you mean to write 'complement'?(2322)
  ```

  Yes, you *did* mean to write `complement`!

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wEvJkN)

Although frankly, if you only use that value when you call the service, you'd get all the same benefits *without* having to write `: UserService` if you inlined the object creation:

```
userService({
  name: '',
  age: 0,
  complement: ''
});
```